# Cypher query: Finding most common path between two nodes filtered by no of relationship

Tags: neo4j

i am new to Neo4j using version 2.0.3.

Currently i am working on a project where we need to find out most common path traversed by user.

DB : there are some fixed checkpoints. Each checkpoint is a node.

when user move from one checkpoint to another then i create relation b/w 2 checkpoints and it is directional .

Relation name is current_time_username;

so checkpoint has more relation is most visited.

now i want to find out most common path b/w 2 checkpoints using Cipher not using java API.

i already check Cipher shortestPath function but not work for this

Comment: create a sample dataset at http://console.neo4j.org and share the URL. Makes it much more easy to come up with an answer.

Comment: Solved : MATCH p=(s:CP)-[:r*]->(e:CP)
RETURN nodes(p) as path, count(*) as c
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 1